# Enable SSLv3 for Minikube Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I have some problems with enabling SSLv3 in my Nginx Ingress used as a Minikube addon.
I have read in [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#legacy-tls) how to do it. It should be as simple as adding single map.
Unfortunately I haven't had much success with it. It added this map in both namespaces - kube-system and the second one in which ingress is created.

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"
  ssl-protocols: "SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

I did it separately and even forced nginx-ingress-controller but nothing happened. I have also found out about nginx-load-balancer-conf ConfigMap in kube-system namespace and added the same entries there too, but it didn't help either.

ssl-protocols seems to be one of few properties which can be defined in [ConfigMap](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/) but no by [annotations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/).

So my question is: Am I making some kind of stupid mistake or Minikube requires some different configuration?

I'm checking result of my actions by [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh).

@Update

I have listed my ingress controller config and there is my list of enabled ssl-protocols containing all I lisited, so I guess config is read, but not used. I have also read the logs but there is no errors there suggesting that for some reason SSLv3 cannot be used.

```
user@server:~$ kubectl exec -it -n kube-system nginx-ingress-controller-658b646bc5-4h562 cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ssl
            is_ssl_passthrough_enabled = false,
        listen_ports = { ssl_proxy = "442", https = "443" },
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

@Update 2

Adding nmap results.

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-01 20:40 CEST
Nmap scan report for my-domain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.038s latency).
rDNS record for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: xxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - C
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Key exchange (dh 2048) of lower strength than certificate key
|       Key exchange (secp256r1) of lower strength than certificate key
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - C
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Key exchange (dh 2048) of lower strength than certificate key
|       Key exchange (secp256r1) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: C

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.95 seconds
```

Comment: Did you create the configmap on the same namespace where the nginx-controller pod is running (ingress-nginx) ?

Comment: Hey, I have edited info in question. I have checked my nginx pod config with command from documentation and I have found that list of protocols from my ConfigMap is applied. Nonetheless `testssl` still complains that SSLv3 is off.

Comment: Try to test using nmap: `nmap -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers yousite.com`. Let me know the result.

Comment: Result included in answer. It also lists just TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

Comment: Hey @Dcortez, I've tried to enable in my lab test and got the same result. BTW, do you have any special reason to enable SSLv3 on your server? I'm asking because SSLv3 has a famous vulnerability that permit 'Man-In-The-Middle' attacks called "POODLE", and AFAIK, there is no fix and the protocol is now obsolote. Take a look [here](https://security.googleblog.com/2015/09/disabling-sslv3-and-rc4.html) and [here](https://security.berkeley.edu/news/poodle-ssl-30-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566)

Comment: I'm aware that this protocol shouldn't be used anymore. I was trying to enable it to quickly test integration before client system can implement TLSv1.2 on test environment.  Client is now updated so supporting SSLv3 is not required anymore, but I'm still curious is there anything wrong with with my take on this, or is there some kind of bug in minikube nginx ingress. Or it may be not supported but then there should be appropriate entry in docs I guess.